# Edit permission using REST - get principalID?

Tags: rest

I'm trying to update permissions on some items using REST in a workflow. I have that working perfectly fine, but I have one issue I didn't foresee when I started planning this setup.

To set the permissions I need to know the principalID of the user, but it seems a user only gets assigned a principalID once the user has been "used" on the site in either a person column or in a permission context.

Now since this setup should take new users into account I cannot be sure they have been used on the site before - and then I can't get their principalID.

How to Work around that using only OOB functionallity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SPWeb.EnsureUser(logonName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) should add a user account to the site, which is what happens when the user has been "used" on the site (or even just visits the site, which presumably they haven't since they are new users).  Once the account is added to the site, you should then be able to get the principleID for it.

According to the JSOM reference for [`SP.Web.ensureUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245233.aspx), the REST URI for calling that method is:

`http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/ensureUser(logonName)`

Comment: Thanks - sounds like just what I need. I'll look into that :-)

Comment: It worked like a charm once I figured out the syntax of the logonName was initials@domain.com and not domain\initials like on the other call :-)